# Sorting for many same table in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to sort same structure table but different data with Angular.
The Plunker example can see [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/4QByuGzekqv0TwxjmTww?p=preview)

The problem is how can I sort for only a specific table not for all the table. I think I can achieve the result by make new variables to store different values for different tables but there is any alternative and efficient way to do it.

Sample data:

```
$scope.friends =
    [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
     {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
     {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
     {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
     {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29}];

$scope.close_friends =
    [{name:'Alan', phone:'555-1212', age:21},
     {name:'Jen', phone:'555-9876', age:29},
     {name:'David', phone:'555-4321', age:24},
     {name:'Raya', phone:'555-5678', age:25},
     {name:'Brok', phone:'555-8765', age:28}];

$scope.very_close_friends =
    [{name:'Peter', phone:'555-1212', age:41},
     {name:'Beck', phone:'555-9876', age:39}];
```

Comment: use a $filter to pick the correct sort for the data.

Comment: could you create a plunker for your answer?

Comment: just $filter the right array i don't see the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the use of the order function:

```
<table class="friend">
    <tr>
     <th>
         <button ng-click="reverse1=!reverse1; predicate = 'name'">Name</button>
         <span class="sortorder" ng-if="predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse1}"></span>
     </th>
     <th>
         <button ng-click="reverse1=!reverse1; predicate = 'phone'">Phone Number</button>
         <span class="sortorder" ng-if="predicate === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse1}"></span>
     </th>
     <th>
         <button ng-click="reverse1=!reverse1; predicate = 'age'">Age</button>
         <span class="sortorder" ng-if=" predicate === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse1}"></span>
     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse1">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zxPOX41fkcKWsA3xRSW7?p=preview

Comment: This is simple and achieve what I need to do. Many thanks!

Comment: Another questions, in the long maintain, can we make a function and handle everything inside that function?

Comment: yes, but is not strictly necessary, just remember to use separate variable for the sorting order or separated sort functions, is up to you.

Comment: I met a problem with the predicate, like if the predicate has blank space like this `my name`, the sort didn't work, it threw some error, do we have any workaround for this?

Comment: because is not a possible predicate for orderby

Answer (score 0):

Add an orderBy property to each array and order by that property in the ng-repeat.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:friends.orderBy">
```

If you're going to really have all kinds of similar lists like this I'd recommend investigating creating a directive or component for it. It will be much more efficient.

Comment: It is actually a little different, not all the same, but thank for your answer!